# membership with custom table in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am trying to convert my vb.net 2010 web forms application into a C# MVC 4 application.  Since my membership is already setup, I would prefer to just continue using the membership provider instead of the simplemembershipprovider.
Hi,

I am using PluralSight to learn MVC, but have not been able to find any reference on how to convert membership code to mvc.

I have a custom table that is linked by UserID to the mememberships User table.  This custom table, asp_customUser, stores additional information about the user.

In the account controller, there is a register action, with the view and model.  The register process does not handle roles, much less my custom data.

What I would like to know is, how do I add roles and custom user information to the database, when part of the fields in the registration view come from the membership library and the other part go to my custom table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the old membership.  Just copy and paste your membership provider from the old web.config to the new one.

If this is running on a different computer, you may need to set the machine key, however, in order for it to be able to correctly validate the password hashes.

You would then remove the Simple membership initialization attribute from the Account controller, and you would need to remove all the other simple membership code.  You would also be giving up the OpenId authentication, because normal membership does not work with WebSecurity, so you would have to remove all that as well.

Comment: I have transferred the code and taken out the simple membership, but how do I combine the membership with my table.  MVC requires separation so I am not sure how I would implement the two with this model. 
Should I create a new controller and then after a user is created save the rest of the information somewhere else?  
Do I need to separate the account controller with a custom account controller.  If yes, how can I make them interact with each other?
Thanks, I hope this makes since.

Comment: @SheriTrager - I don't understand what you mean by "combine the membership with the table".  You said you were already using this database, there should be no need to change anything.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not clear on this.  Having a hard time explaining it.  Using the membership provider the registration information is saved automatically, i.e. none of those tables are in the entities.  Since I need to save additional information when saving the registration information, how do I capture that information.  Do I add the additional fields to the registration view and they to the model?  How would I save the additional information when a new user is registering. 
I hope this is clearer.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @SheriTrager - the same way you did it in Web Forms, Membership works the exact same way.  If you want to register new users, why are you using the old membership system?  You already have your users registered.

Comment: I need to use the existing membership tables in the database.  I read somewhere that simplemembership doesn't use the same tables.  In my web forms application, I use the membership provider in a few places to access data.  If I could use simple membership that would be great because there is an example of that on pluralsight.

Answer (score 0):

When we wanted to extend the membership class we inherited the base membership class and used all the fields in it and the tables linked to it and then create an additional database table with a FK linked to the id in the membership table.  Any additional parameters where in the new table and extended class and any standard parameters were in the std membership table and standard class.